# Execute PowerShell command from cmd - quotes issue

Tags: powershell, cmd, double-quotes

I have to execute two commands (including a PowerShell one) in new console window. Let me explain:

I am able to execute a PowerShell command from `cmd` in a new console window (I can specify the command inside quotes):

```
start /W cmd /K powershell -command "&{Write-Host 'Hello World!';}"
```

And I can execute two commands (I can write both commands in quotes):

```
start /W cmd /K "echo Hello && echo World"
```

But how can I do it together (execute two commands, one of them PowerShell)? I would like to do it **without** any .bat or .ps script.

I tried something like following (and some variations with escaping character), but I cannot deal with this quotes issue (there are quotes for joining two commands and inside quotes for *PowerShell* command).

```
start /W cmd /K "echo Hello && powershell -command "&{Write-Host 'Hello World!';}""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape `&` in powershell's ScriptBlock for cmd:

`start /W cmd /K "echo Hello && powershell -command "^&{Write-Host 'Hello World!';}""`

Comment: Ah, so the problem was with &, not quotes... It works, thanks for help.